# Last element in OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I have `od` of type `OrderedDict`. I want to access its most recently added (key, value) pair. `od.popitem(last = True)` would do it, but would also remove the pair from `od` which I don't want.

What's a good way to do that? Can /should I do this:

```
class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
  def last(self):
    return next(reversed(self))
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Using `next(reversed(od))` is a perfect way of accessing the most-recently added element.  The class `OrderedDict` uses a doubly linked list for the dictionary items and implements [`__reversed__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__), so this implementation gives you O(1) access to the desired element.  Whether it is worthwhile to subclass `OrderedDict()` for this simple operation may be questioned, but there's nothing actually wrong with this approach.

Comment: But that only returns the key of the last item in the OD, right? not the entire item (key, value). `next(reversed(OrderedDict([(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')])))`  gives  `2` not `(2, 'c')`

Comment: @hobs: Yes, it only gives you the key.  How to get the value given the key is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: FWIW, O(2) and O(1) are asymptotically equivalent

Comment: In Python 3.5, you can do next(reversed(od.values())) to get the last value

Comment: Also note that if you want the *first* element you should use `next(iter(od))`

Comment: Just a clarification: From line 82 of collections.py (with the Python 2.7.8 source, not sure about newer 2.7 versions) it appears that the internal linked list is actually a cycle. At first this answer did not make sense to me, because the first node of a doubly linked list need not have the final node as a "predecessor" node. It could have a "null" node, and the final node might similarly have a "null" node as its successor. But the OrderedDict implementation cycles back, so the O(1) access comes from the ability to get the final node by a simple array access from the root node's data.

Comment: No wonder that in Python 3.5 you can do `next(reversed(od.items()))` to get the last `(key, value)` pair.

Comment: How to get last n elements from OrderedDict?

Comment: @Artur You can use `itertools.islice()` on `reversed(od)`.

Answer (score 28):

God, I wish this was all built-in functionality...

Here's something to save you precious time. Tested in Python 3.7. `od` is your OrderedDict.

```
# Get first key
next(iter(od))

# Get last key
next(reversed(od))

# Get first value
od[next(iter(od))]

# Get last value
od[next(reversed(od))]

# Get first key-value tuple
next(iter(od.items()))

# Get last key-value tuple
next(reversed(od.items()))
```

Comment: Good examples, only a single observation, keys method isn't necessary

Comment: are all these operations O(1)?

Comment: @KnightKnight as there's no sorting or comparisons involved, and given most of Python's collection methods should be lazy, I'd wager yes. But don't take my word for it in an interview.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for me ^^

Answer (score 18):

A little magic from timeit can help here...

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class MyOrderedDict1(OrderedDict):
  def last(self):
    k=next(reversed(self))
    return (k,self[k])

class MyOrderedDict2(OrderedDict):
  def last(self):
     out=self.popitem()
     self[out[0]]=out[1]
     return out

class MyOrderedDict3(OrderedDict):
  def last(self):
     k=(list(self.keys()))[-1]
     return (k,self[k])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  from timeit import Timer

  N=100

  d1=MyOrderedDict1()
  for i in range(N): d1[i]=i

  print ("d1",d1.last())

  d2=MyOrderedDict2()
  for i in range(N): d2[i]=i

  print ("d2",d2.last())

  d3=MyOrderedDict3()
  for i in range(N): d3[i]=i

  print("d3",d3.last())



  t=Timer("d1.last()",'from __main__ import d1')
  print ("OrderedDict1",t.timeit())
  t=Timer("d2.last()",'from __main__ import d2')
  print ("OrderedDict2",t.timeit())
  t=Timer("d3.last()",'from __main__ import d3')
  print ("OrderedDict3",t.timeit())
```

results in:

```
d1 (99, 99)
d2 (99, 99)
d3 (99, 99)
OrderedDict1 1.159217119216919
OrderedDict2 3.3667118549346924
OrderedDict3 24.030261993408203
```

(Tested on python3.2, Ubuntu Linux).

As pointed out by @SvenMarnach, the method you described is quite efficient compared to the other two ways I could cook up.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is fine, however the default iterator is only over the keys, so your example will only return the last key. What you actually want is:

```
class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def last(self):
        return list(self.items())[-1]
```

This gives the `(key, value)` pairs, not just the keys, as you wanted.

Note that on pre-3.x versions of Python, `OrderedDict.items()` returns a list, so you don't need the `list()` call, but later versions return a [dictionary view object](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dictionary-view-objects), so you will.

Edit: As noted in the comments, the quicker operation is to do:

```
class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def last(self):
        key = next(reversed(self))
        return (key, self[key])
```

Although I must admit I do find this uglier in the code (I never liked getting the key then doing `x[key]` to get the value separately, I prefer getting the `(key, value)` tuple) - depending on the importance of speed and your preferences, you may wish to pick the former option.

Comment: This will be an O(n) operation, of course.  It would be better to use the original implementation to get the key, and get the value by normal dictionary access. (And when you anyway have to buld a list, `[-1]` is much easier than `next(reversed(...))`.)

Comment: You make a good point, corrected. Too easy to get locked into one way of solving a problem.