# Get last value of an OrderedDict in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917178/last-element-in-ordereddict) is way to get the last *key* of an OrderedDict in Python3.

I need to get last value of an OrderedDict in Python3 without conversions to `list`.

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 

>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dd = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2)
>>> next(reversed(dd))
'b'

>>> next(reversed(dd.keys()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

>>> next(reversed(dd.items()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

>>> next(reversed(dd.values()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

Comment: Oops, looks like I overlooked the obvious solution: `dd[next(reversed(dd))]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use that key to index the dictionary:

```
dd[next(reversed(dd))]
```

For example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dd = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2)
print(dd[next(reversed(dd))])     # 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in Python 3.8 (https://bugs.python.org/issue33462).

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dd = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2)
>>> next(reversed(dd.keys()))
'b'
>>> next(reversed(dd.values()))
2
>>> next(reversed(dd.items()))
('b', 2)
```